# ROS Roboearth Ubuntu 12.04 vision_opencv linking error

Tags: opencv, computer-vision, ubuntu-12.04, ros

I have tried asking [this question](http://answers.ros.org/question/54777/install-errors-roboearth-ubuntu-1204-fuerte-vision_opencv/) on ROS answers with no luck so I am going to try here.

I am trying to compile the [ROS Roboearth package](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth) and there seem to be some linking errors with vision_opencv.

When I first tried compiling via the instructions provided I was not able to do build because I had old compiler and I did not have Fuerte. So, I upgraded my Ubuntu to 12.04 and updated to ROS Fuerte.

I then realized that 12.04 does not have the required ros-fuerte-vision-opencv2 dependency. So, I compiled and built OpenCV 2.4.3 from source, that went great. I then realized that I am also not able to pull ros-fuerte-vision-opencv which I again got from [here](http://www.ros.org/wiki/vision_opencv), checked out the "fuerte" branch and compiled in /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv.

Now, when I try to make roboearth via

`rosmake roboearth`

I get the following linking errors.

Thank you for your help. It may be just my lack of knowledge of C++ but I tried everything from checking dependencies to re-setting the order of compiler flags and dependencies and I just can't seem to get this to work.

```
[rosmake-1] Starting >>> ar_pose [ make ]                                                                                            
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lines_vision: 30.7 sec ] [ ar_pose: 4.2 sec ]                                        [ 2 Active 47/103 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sasha/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build'
  [ 70%] Built target rosbuild_precompile
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sasha/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build'
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sasha/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build'
  make[3]: Entering directory `/home/sasha/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build'
  Linking CXX executable ../bin/ar_multi
  CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/src/ar_multi.o: In function `ar_pose::ARSinglePublisher::arInit()':
  /home/sasha/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/src/ar_multi.cpp:140: undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
  CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/src/ar_multi.o: In function `CvBridge':
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:67: undefined reference to `cvCreateImageHeader'
  CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/src/ar_multi.o: In function `~CvBridge':
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:73: undefined reference to `cvReleaseImageHeader'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:78: undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
  CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/src/ar_multi.o: In function `sensor_msgs::CvBridge::reallocIfNeeded_(_IplImage**, CvSize, int, int)':
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:91: undefined reference to `cvReleaseImage'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:97: undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
  CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/src/ar_multi.o: In function `sensor_msgs::CvBridge::reallocIfNeeded(_IplImage**, int, int)':
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:109: undefined reference to `cvGetSize'
  CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/src/ar_multi.o: In function `sensor_msgs::CvBridge::fromImage(sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:199: undefined reference to `cvInitMatHeader'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:200: undefined reference to `cvGetImage'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:229: undefined reference to `cvCreateMat'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:230: undefined reference to `cvConvertScale'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:236: undefined reference to `cvConvertScale'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:243: undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:245: undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:247: undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:249: undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:253: undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
  CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/src/ar_multi.o:/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:255: more undefined references to `cvCvtColor' follow
  CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/src/ar_multi.o: In function `sensor_msgs::CvBridge::fromImage(sensor_msgs::Image_<std::allocator<void> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >)':
  /opt/ros/fuerte/stacks/vision_opencv/cv_bridge/include/cv_bridge/CvBridge.h:293: undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/ar_multi] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sasha/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ar_multi.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sasha/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sasha/ros/stacks/ccny_vision/ar_pose/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package ar_pose written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/sasha/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130212-145046/ar_pose/build_output.log
[rosmake-1] Finished <<< ar_pose [FAIL] [ 4.31 seconds ]                                                                             
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package ar_pose. 
[ rosmake ] Waiting for other threads to complete.                           
[ rosmake ] Last 40 lines_vision: 182.3 sec ]                                                            [ 1 Active 47/103 Complete ]
{-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cvReleaseMat'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::reshape(int, int, int const*) const'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cvSetZero'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::warpPerspective(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, int, int, cv::Scalar_<double> const&)'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::getTextSize(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int, double, int, int*)'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::zeros(int, int, int)'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(cv::MatExpr const&)'
  ../lib/libDVision.so: undefined reference to `cv::read(cv::FileNode const&, std::vector<cv::KeyPoint, std::allocator<cv::KeyPoint> >&)'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::DescriptorMatcher::DescriptorCollection::~DescriptorCollection()'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::FlannBasedMatcher::train()'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cvCvtColor'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::MatConstIterator::seek(int const*, bool)'
  ../lib/libDVision.so: undefined reference to `cv::FeatureDetector::~FeatureDetector()'
  ../lib/libDUtilsCV.so: undefined reference to `cv::line(cv::Mat&, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Point_<int>, cv::Scalar_<double> const&, int, int, int)'
  ../lib/libDVision.so: undefined reference to `cv::Exception::Exception(int, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_InputArray const&, cv::Size_<int>, int, cv::_OutputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&)'
  ../lib/libDVision.so: undefined reference to `cv::WriteStructContext::~WriteStructContext()'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copySize(cv::Mat const&)'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cvCreateImageHeader'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::inv(int) const'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::copyTo(cv::_OutputArray const&) const'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::Mat(cv::Mat const&, cv::Range const&, cv::Range const&)'
  ../lib/libDVision.so: undefined reference to `cv::operator<<(cv::FileStorage&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&)'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::flann::IndexParams::~IndexParams()'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cvGetSize'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::Mat::deallocate()'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::_InputArray::_InputArray(double const&)'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cvCreateImage'
  ../lib/libDUtilsCV.so: undefined reference to `cv::namedWindow(std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > const&, int)'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::Algorithm::~Algorithm()'
  ../lib/libObjectDetectorFunctions.so: undefined reference to `cv::FlannBasedMatcher::FlannBasedMatcher(cv::Ptr<cv::flann::IndexParams> const&, cv::Ptr<cv::flann::SearchParams> const&)'
  ../lib/libDVision.so: undefined reference to `cv::Algorithm::set(char const*, bool)'
  collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
  make[3]: *** [../bin/ObjectDetector] Error 1
  make[3]: Leaving directory `/home/sasha/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
  make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ObjectDetector.dir/all] Error 2
  make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/sasha/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
  make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
  make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/sasha/ros/stacks/roboearth/re_vision/build'
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------}
[ rosmake ] Output from build of package re_vision written to:
[ rosmake ]    /home/sasha/.ros/rosmake/rosmake_output-20130212-145046/re_vision/build_output.log
[rosmake-0] Finished <<< re_vision [FAIL] [ 182.31 seconds ]                                                                         
[ rosmake ] Halting due to failure in package re_vision.
```

Comment: I believe the problem is somewhere in `roboearth/re_vision` where it tries to use absolute or broken libs in `vision_opencv`. [Here](https://ipvs.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/roboearth/repos/public/tags/latest/re_vision/CMakeLists.txt) is the link to re_vision CMakeLists.txt and [this](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/blob/groovy-devel/cv_bridge/CMakeLists.txt) is `vision_opencv/cv_bridge` CMakeLists.txt. And [here](https://github.com/ros-perception/vision_opencv/blob/fuerte-devel/opencv2/manifest.xml) is `vision_opencv/opencv2` manifext.xml. I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I was able to solve the problem.

First I did `sudo apt-get update` and I saw that I was getting the following message:

`W: Duplicate sources.list entry http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/ precise/partner i386 Packages (/var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_precise_partner_binary-i386_Packages)`

To resolve this I went to `Synaptic Package Manager-> Settings -> Repositories -> Other Software' and unchecked "Canonical Partners - Added by software center".

Then did `sudo apt-get update` again. This solved the above problem.

Then, I went to the following file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list` and saw that the url was commented out. I uncommented the following line `deb http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu precise main` and ran `sudo apt-get update` again.

After this point I was able to install all of the dependencies which are needed for roboearth and via apt-get and was able to successfully make roboearth with `rosmake roboearth`